# Mac: Edit in Filezilla with Sublime text always open a new Sublime window

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2, filezilla

With my **Mac**, everytime I want to Edit a file from **Filezilla**, it open a new **Sublime text** window. Is there a way to tell Filezilla to open the file in the current window if it already exist?

Comment: Are you sure it opens a new instance and not just a new window? (Meaning: Are there really two Sublime Text dock icons appearing?)

Comment: You're right, it open a new window, not a new instance. I'll correct that in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding

```
"open_files_in_new_window": false
```

to your user settings.

This is a Mac-only option, so it should not affect the usual behavior of Sublime Text that is common for all platforms.

Comment: Add this setting to where, in sublime?

Comment: Where Can i find the settings.